Differentiability of an integral depending on a parameter
Let $f$ be a function in $L^1 ([0,1])$, and for $y \in [0,1]$ consider $$F(y) = \int_{[0,1]} (1+ |f|)^y dx$$
Is $F$ differentiable in $(0,1)$? If it is, what is its derivative?
I know that that, given $(X, \mathfrak{M}, \mu)$ a measurable space, $f : X \times (a,b) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $F(y) = \int_X f(x,y) d\mu$, such that:
(1) $f(x,y) \in L^1(X) \; \forall y \in (a,b)$
(2) $y \in (a,b) \mapsto f(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} $ is differentiable $\forall x \in X $
(3) It exists $g(x) \in L^1(X)$ such that $|\partial_2 f(x,y)| \leq g(x) \; \forall (x,y) \in X \times (a,b) $
Then $F(y)$ is differentiable and $F'(y) = \int_X \partial_2 f(x,y) dx $
It's easy to see that (1) and (2) are true, however I can't find a $g$ like that in condition (3). 
All I could do is showing that $$|\partial_2 (1+|f|)^y| = (1+|f|)^y \ln (1+|f|) \leq (1+|f|) \ln (1+|f|)$$ But I don't know if that's in $L^1$. If I use the fact that $\ln(1+|f|) \leq |f|$ I obtain $|f| + |f|^2$, that is not in $L^1$ in general (e.g. if $f(x)= \frac{1}{ \sqrt{x}}$).
Does such a $g$ exist? If not, is there another theorem that can be applied or another way to determine the differentiability of $F$?
